# Complex conjugation & Feynman's path integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, path-integral

In Feynman's path integral approach in quantum mechanics, a probability amplitude can be written as

$$\langle\Psi_{+}|\Psi_{-}\rangle=\int D\Psi\ e^{iS[\Psi]} .$$

I want to show that complex conjugating this equation gives $$\langle\Psi_{+}|\Psi_{-}\rangle^{*}=\langle\Psi_{-}|\Psi_{+}\rangle.$$

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Let me fix my notation. In Heisenberg picture, we have

$$
\langle \, x_f , t  \, | \, x_i, 0 \, \rangle =
\int [dx] \, \exp \left[\, \frac{i}{\hbar} \int_{0}^{t} d\tau \, L(q, \dot{q}) \, \right].
$$

If $x$ is real then

$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle \, x_f , t  \, | \, x_i, 0 \, \rangle^{*} &= \left( \int [dx] \, \exp \left[\, \frac{i}{\hbar} \int_{0}^{t} d\tau \, L(q, \dot{q}) \, \right] \right)^{*}  \\
&=\int [dx] \, \exp \left[\, -\frac{i}{\hbar} \int_{0}^{t} d\tau \, L(q, \dot{q}) \, \right].
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, it is simply a matter of reversing the integral:

$$
\langle \, x_f , t  \, | \, x_i, 0 \, \rangle^{*} = \int [dx] \, \exp \left[\, \frac{i}{\hbar} \int_{t}^{0} d\tau \, L(q, \dot{q}) \, \right]
$$

which, by definition -- since $x(0) = x_i$ with $x(t) = x_f$ --, you get

$$
\langle \, x_f , t  \, | \, x_i, 0 \, \rangle^{*} =
\langle \, x_i , 0  \, | \, x_f, t \, \rangle.
$$

You can do yourself the field theoretic case. It is straightforward.